# Springboot 2.2.1 : NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.setHostHeader

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat8

I recently upgraded my springboot application form 2.0.9 to 2.2.1
However, during deployment of my application, I get the below error related to tomcat. Tomcat dependency is added in my application via spring-boot-starter-web. My deployment container has Tomcat 8.5

```
2019 12 05 14:05:45#+00#ERROR#org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase##anonymous#localhost-startStop-1#na#s2k4640ult#permitmgmtcoreaic#web##na#na#na#na#ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/permitmgmt-core]]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:836)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatServletWebServerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/ServletWebServerFactoryConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.setHostHeader(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:603)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:152)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:132)
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:92)
at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5245)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 10 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.setHostHeader(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.customizeRemoteIpValve(TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:189)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.customize(TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:85)
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.embedded.TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.customize(TomcatWebServerFactoryCustomizer.java:60)
at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.lambda$postProcessBeforeInitialization$0(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:72)
at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.lambda$null$0(LambdaSafe.java:287)
at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$LambdaSafeCallback.invoke(LambdaSafe.java:159)
at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.lambda$invoke$1(LambdaSafe.java:286)
at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.forEach(Collections.java:1082)
at org.springframework.boot.util.LambdaSafe$Callbacks.invoke(LambdaSafe.java:286)
at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:72)
at org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(WebServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:58)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1795)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
... 28 common frames omitted
```

What should be corrected here?

Comment: Spring Boot 2.2.1 bundles Tomcat 9.0.27.  Have you tried updating Tomcat to the same version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot is trying to call a method that [was added in 8.5.44](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57665#c24). Presumably you are using a Tomcat 8.5.x release that is older than that and, therefore, upgrading to a recent 8.5.x release should fix the problem.

Spring Boot shouldn't be so sensitive to the version of Tomcat to which an application is being deployed. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/19308) to improve things.

Comment: Thanks Andy! The solution fixed my issue.